# Leaflet with GeoServer in background too slow for GeoTiff

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms, web-mapping, geotiff-tiff

I am implementing a Leaflet web-map application to display several GeoTiffs. The GeoTiffs are each ~300MB and published by GeoServer as WMS. In Leaflet I add them through L.tileLayer.wms.

I also perform some grouping of the layer before adding them to the map.

My problem is now that the layers published by the GeoServer load very slow in the Leaflet application, whereas the OpenLayers​ preview offered by GeoServer is pretty fast.

Any Idea what this might cause?

Comment: I'm not sure about the difference between the open layers preview and your leaflet map, but you should definitely follow some of [this](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/data.html#setup-geotiff-data-for-fast-rendering) advice if you are able.  Optimizing your TIFFs can singificantly improve their performance...

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I already noticed that compression of the images is not good for the performance, but I never tried the inner tiling.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this? It's not clear how you are loading them in Leaflet.

Comment: Could it be reprojection

Comment: No, I had a look at this.

Comment: We still don't know how you are doing the load, or what else you tried. If this is still a problem, please update the question to provide more information.

Comment: Please take the [Tour] for an introduction to the site and its protocols.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: Does the OpenLayers embeded in GeoServer (to give the preview) have any advantages over say some OpenLayers code on a separate client, or indeed Leaflet? It might be worth checking.  Then you'd know if it was genuinely a Leaflet over OpenLayers issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [MapProxy](http://mapproxy.org/) to cache tiles. It will agressively cache all requested tiles, and save GeoServer the work of cutting down the geotiff at every request.

Comment: Since GeoServer has GeoWebCache built in, this is un-necessary.